# PHP: Textile giving me single quotes instead of apostrophes

Tags: php, textile

I'm using v2.0 of ClassTextile.php, with the following call:

```
$testimonial_text = $textile->TextileRestricted($_POST['testimonial']);
```

... and all of my apostrophes (ex. It's hot in here) are being translated to ASCII `&#8216;` (which is a single quote, which slopes the wrong way).  What it should be is ASCII `&#8217;`.  I've also tried using `TextileThis()` and I have the same problem.

If I go and try it on Textile's website (http://textile.thresholdstate.com/), it gives the correct ASCII code.  So why isn't it working with the downloadable library? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this again and it works. Weird.

Have since switched to Markdown, regardless. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you really copy-pasted the text from your source code to the form on their website? If this still yields the same result, you should probably upgrade your version.

Comment: I'm using the latest version (just downloaded it again from the website), and my code is almost verbatim what the example code is (what I had reprinted in my question).

Comment: That does not sound as if the example string had been copy-pasted - The two characters look exactly the same (depoending on your fonts settings) but translate to different values. Try copy-pasting the following two characters into the input box on the link you provided: ''

Answer (score 0):

Hmm code looks clean, I would suggest passing in the POST and a variable instead of directly just to see if there is some kinda bug. I don't think the results will change just ruling out that option.

```
$var = $_POST['testimonial'];
$testimonial_text = $textile->TextileRestricted($var);
```